# My array is gettting an error because it's being defined as a singular integer

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

The point of this program is to output whether a series of digits (the number of digits undefined) is sorted or not (largest to smallest or smallest to largest).
I have defined my array in my function parameter, and I am trying to use a for loop to store the user's input, as long as it is above 0, in said array.
However, I am getting the error `argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type int*`.
The exact error is `the argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type int*`.
It is referring to line 22 and 23, these two;
`isSorted(list[2000]);` and
`bool is = isSorted(list[2000]);`.
I know this means my for loop is assigning a single value to my variable repeatedly from reading similar questions however I can not figure out how to fix this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isSorted(int list[]);

int main()
{    
    int i;
    int list[2000];
    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        int j;
        while (j > 0)
        {
            cin >> j;
            list[i] = j;
        }
    }
    isSorted(list[2000]);
    bool is = isSorted(list[2000]);
    if (is == true)
        cout << "sorted";
    else
        cout << "unsorted";

    return 0;
}

bool isSorted(int list[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1] || list[i] < list[i - 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error from the compiler and indicate which line it refers to. There is more than one problem with this code btw. `list` is a poor choice for a variable name, especially with `using namespace std;`

Comment: `isSorted(list[2000])` is passing the 2000th element of `list` (which doesn't exist) into `isSorted`. I think you want `isSorted(list)`

Comment: Avoid using magic numbers like 2000. If someone changes `int list[2000];` into `int list[1000];`, then `for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++)` is going take `list[i]` out of bounds. You'll also want to think over the bounds of the loop with respect to `list[i + 1]` and `list[i - 1]`.

Comment: the exact error is the argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type int* it is referring to line 22 and 23, these two; isSorted(list[2000]);
    bool is = isSorted(list[2000]);

Comment: jenn7542 Please let me know how I can make my answer more useful to you. (And by the way, helpful information is better added to the question itself, instead of hidden down here in the comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I removed unused variable `k`.
- Made 2000 parameterized (and set to 5 for testing).
- In `isSorted` you are not allowed to return
  `true` in the `else` as if your first element test would end in else you would return `true` immediately not testing other elements. But those later elements can be unsorted as well.
- In `isSorted` you are not allowed to run the loop as `for(i = 0; i < 2000; i++)`, because you add inside the for loop 1 to `i` and end up querying for `i == 1999` `list[2000]`, which is element number 2001 and not inside your array. This is correct instead: `for (i = 0; i < 1999; i++)`. You also do not need to check into both directions.
- You cannot call `isSorted(list[2000])` as this would call is sorted with an int and not an int array as parameter.
- You write int j without initializing it and then query `while j > 0` before you `cin << j`. This is undefined behaviour, while most likely j will be zero, there is no guarantee. But most likely you never enter the while loop and never do `cin`
- I renamed the `isSorted` as you just check in your example for ascending  order. If you want to check for descending order you are welcome to train your programming skills and implementing this yourself.

Here is the code with the fixes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isSortedInAscendingOrder(int list[]);

const int size = 5; // Set this to 2000 again if you want

int main()
{
    int i;
    int list[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while(j <= 0)
        {
            cin >> j;
            if(j <= 0)
                cout << "rejected as equal or smaller zero" << endl;
        }
        list[i] = j;
    }
    if (isSortedInAscendingOrder(list))
        cout << "sorted" << endl;
    else
        cout << "unsorted" << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool isSortedInAscendingOrder(int list[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size -1; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Good point about the inadvisable return from else, though fixing the logic is not actually part of the question. If you do fix the logic, you will have to spend some work on  detecting ascending OR descending sorting...

Comment: Making the array size configurable is good, but since `size` is not a constant this code will not work on all compilers. Variable length arrays aren't standard.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well you are exactly right that there is not reverse sorted check, but I was too lazy to fix this :). I will just rename the function and leave the remaining work for the student. I still think fixing logic a bit is not a terrible idea.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks did not know this can be a compiler problem. Fixed this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you definitely helped me sort through the logic of it! The program is now running as it should

Answer (score 1):

This is a definition of an array of 2000 integers.

```
int list[2000];
```

This is reading the 2000th entry in that array and undefined, because the highest legal index to access is 1999. Remember that the first legal index is 0.

```
list[2000]
```

So yes, from point of view of the compiler, the following only gives a single integer on top of being undefined behaviour (i.e. "evil").

```
isSorted(list[2000]);
```

You probably should change to this, in order to fix the immediate problem - and get quite close to what you probably want. It names the whole array as parameter. It will decay to a pointer to int (among other things loosing the information of size, but you hardcoded that inside the function; better change that by the way).

```
isSorted(list);
```

Delete the ignored first occurence (the one alone on a line), keep the second (the one assigning to a bool variable).

On the other hand, the logic of a your sorting check is flawed, it will often access outside the array, for indexes 0 and 1999. I.e. at the start and end of your loop. You need to loop over slightly less than the whole array and only use one of the two conditions.

I.e. do

```
for (i = 1; i < 2000; i++)
{
    if (list[i] < list[i - 1])
/* ... */
```

The logic for checking ascending or descending sorting would have to be more complex. The question is not asking to fix that logic, so I stick with fixing the issues according to the original version (which did not mention two-way-sorting).
You actually did not ask about fixing the logic for that. But here is a hint:
Either use two loops, which you can break from as soon as you find a conflict, but do not return from the fuction immediatly.
Or use one loop and keep a flag of whether ascending or descending order has been broken. Then return true if either flag is still clear (or both, in case of all identical values) or return false if both are set.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question, and thank you my errors are now running perfectly!!